# How vagrant can be helpful for development purpose

Tags: vagrant

I have heard a lot about vagrant tool and exploring it much more. People say that it makes development environment set up easier so that every developers will have same set of configuration in their machines.

But What I really dont understand is that how it can be useful for developers for development purpose. (since I dont see any such thing like GUI boxes where we can do coding same like in our Ubuntu local machine. SO basically vagrant is like a server machine without GUI)

As far as I understand I would not be able to do coding in those vagrant VM machines.
This is my understanding:

> I have a rails project which I am working on. I can set up the
>   development environment in vagrant specified in Vagrant config file
>   and ssh into vM and pull my latest code repos and run it.

But for development I need to set up the same in my local computer so that I can start coding. Once I push the changes to github I can then again pull the latest code from VM and test it.

> So basically what I understand is that it can be used for QA to test
>   my app in an environment which they set up in vagrant so that we can
>   ensure that it would work without any issues in the Prod enviorment
>   which is set up using the same Vagrant config file. And for setting up
>   those  environment vagrant becomes useful.

So for a developer he has to set up vagrant to test his app and also he has to set up the same in his local machine for doing coding as well. 
Please correct me if my understanding is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vagrant has [synced folders](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/synced-folders/index.html) which means that the code on your development machine can be directly shared into the VM (you can also use other methods to do the reverse)

The default setup of Vagrant shares the folder that contains your `Vagrantfile` into `/vagrant` on the VM... try it out.

So on your dev machine you would have your code editor and code files, and on the VM you would be running your web server and rails etc... Then you point a browser directly at the VM IP or to localhost if you are using a port forward... makes it very easy and you definitely do not have to re copy the files into the VM each time either manually or via Git.

Answer (score 0):

Matt Cooper is correct.
Also I found Vagrant very useful for team work.
It helps to get identical development environments for all members and avoid the problem "But it worked on my machine!!!".

Answer (score 0):

If developer and QA use the same Vagrantfile file in this case we are sure that both using the same environment and also it helps with reproducing issue